# polyglossia does not work with hyperref if main language is RTL

Tags: hyperref, polyglossia, arabic

Dear Ladies and Gentlemen,

If polyglossia is used with hyperref and the main language is set to Arabic, a rtl language, the file does not compile, as can be seen in the below example. If the main language is ltr, there is no problem. Does anybody know a solution to this problem?

With best wishes and thanks for your interest.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage[xetex]{hyperref}

\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.4]{Scheherazade}

\setotherlanguage{english}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.4]{Scheherazade}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Mapping=tex-text,Renderer=ICU]{Charis SIL}



\begin{document}

السلام عليكم

\begin{english}
\url{https://www.google.de}
\end{english}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show us  the error message.

Comment: The console says that the current roman font does not contain the arabic script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\href` instead of `\url` in this case `\englishfont` is used for hyperlink text.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{polyglossia}


\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.4]{Scheherazade}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Mapping=tex-text,Renderer=ICU]{Charis SIL}



\begin{document}

السلام عليكم

\begin{english}
\href{https://www.google.de}{www.google.de}
\end{english}


\end{document}
```

Or just add

```
\let\arabicfonttt\ttfamily
```

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{polyglossia}


\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.4]{Scheherazade}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Mapping=tex-text,Renderer=ICU]{Charis SIL}

\let\arabicfonttt\ttfamily

\begin{document}

السلام عليكم

\begin{english}
\hrl{https://www.google.de}
\end{english}


\end{document}
```

Comment: dear salim bou, thank you very much for your advice, it works fine.