# Customising footnote marks with reledmac

Tags: footnotes, reledmac

In the manual of `reledmac` there are, on page 32, subsubsection 6.5.2, some remarks about customising the footnote marks of familiar footnotes, but it seems to me not clear how to use this instruction to achieve a different appearance of the footnote marks.

Does anyone know something about this matter?

I would like to put an Arabic text facing its translation into German, thereby using two layers of familiar footnotes, one referring to the translation and the other to the original text. The footnotes referring to the LTR text are LTR and those referring to the RTL text are RTL.

Now, I would like to have the first layer, `\footnoteA`, with footnote marks in Arabic numerals and brackets around, and the second layer, `\footnoteB`, with alphabetic characters in Arabic and also brackets around.

I have tried a kind of "solution" which at least puts brackets around the alphabetic footnote marks in the `\footnoteB` layer at the bottom of the page, but the remaining features I could not achieve.

This is a MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossiasetspace}
\usepackage[series={A,B},nocritical,noend]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
 \setmainlanguage[spelling=old,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Renderer=ICU]{Charis SIL}

\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Mapping=tex-text,Renderer=ICU]{Charis SIL}

\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.4]{Scheherazade}

\linenumincrement*{2}
\firstlinenum*{1}
\setlength{\Lcolwidth}{0.5\textwidth}
\setlength{\Rcolwidth}{0.4\textwidth} 

\newcommand{
\فب
}[1]{\footnoteB{\hspace{1ex}#1}}

%\renewcommand*{\thefootnoteB}{\alph{footnoteB}}

\bhooknoteX{\renewcommand{\thefootnoteB}{\textarabic{(\alph{footnoteB})}}}
%\bhooknoteX{\renewcommand{\bodyfootmarkB}{\textarabic{(\alph{footnoteB})}}}

\begin{document}

%\numberlinefalse

\AtBeginPairs{\sloppy}
\begin{pairs}

\begin{Rightside} 
\begin{RTL}
\begin{Arabic}
\begin{spacing}{2}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
نحمدك اللهمّ على نعم يؤذن الحمد بازديادها، ونصلي على نبيك محمد هادي الأمة\فب{يعني أمة محمد.} لرشادها
\pend    
\endnumbering
\end{spacing}
\end{Arabic}
\end{RTL}
\end{Rightside}

\begin{Leftside} 
\begin{german}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\noindent
Wir preisen dich, Gott, für Gnadengaben, deren Lobpreis von ihrem\footnoteA{\hspace{1ex}D.h. der Gnadengaben} Anwachsen kündet, und wir bitten um Segen für deinen Propheten Muḥammad, der die Gemeinde auf den rechten Weg führt.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{german}
\end{Leftside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would help if you described how you'd like to change them from their defaults.

Comment: indeed. For now, I don't know what you need.

Comment: Dear jon,dear Maieul, thank you very much for your attention, I have edited my question, and I hope that it may be somehow clearer now.

Comment: You didn't provide a MWE, as your example is not ready-to-run.  Next time, please do it… I will answer you soon.

Comment: Excuse me please, I made a mistake, it seems that I did not copy the whole code, some lines at the beginning were missing. I have supplied them, and hope that it now works. Thank you very much for your efforts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank, the new formulation of your question is clearer than the first one.

However, the code your provided is not useful, as it not a MWE, which is ready to run (there is no documentclass, and some package loading are missing). Please read this topic:
https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/7712.

However, I was able to recreate a MWE. So I can answer to your question.

You tried to use \bhooknoteX, which is not the direct way to get you result, and which seems to pertubate (I don't know exactly why, it is maybe a bug of reledmac) the character/typesetting detection.

The handbook explained you, however, that is was possible to directly modify the footnotemark inside the footnote text, by redefining `\footfootmarkA` (and `\footfootmarkB`). That will also be useful to automatically insert your hspace, and not insert it manually.

As this manipulate command with arobase inside, you must use `\makeateletter…\makeatother structure`.

Here the code to put in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\footfootmarkA}{(\textsuperscript{\@thefnmarkA})\hspace{1ex}}
\renewcommand{\footfootmarkB}{\textarabic{(\textsuperscript{\@thefnmarkB})}\hspace{1ex}}
\makeatother
```

And here, the full MWE, with the correction of you'r "wrong" code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[noend,noeledsec]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage[spelling=old,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Renderer=ICU]{Charis SIL}

\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Mapping=tex-text,Renderer=ICU]{Charis SIL}

\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.4]{Scheherazade}

\linenumincrement*{2}
\firstlinenum*{1}
\setlength{\Lcolwidth}{0.5\textwidth}
\setlength{\Rcolwidth}{0.4\textwidth} 

\newcommand{
\فب
}[1]{\footnoteB{#1}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\footfootmarkA}{(\textsuperscript{\@thefnmarkA})\hspace{1ex}}
\renewcommand{\footfootmarkB}{\textarabic{(\textsuperscript{\@thefnmarkB})}\hspace{1ex}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

%\numberlinefalse

\AtBeginPairs{\sloppy}
\begin{pairs}

\begin{Rightside} 
\begin{RTL}
\begin{Arabic}
\begin{spacing}{2}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
نحمدك اللهمّ على نعم يؤذن الحمد بازديادها، ونصلي على نبيك محمد هادي الأمة\فب{يعني أمة محمد.} لرشادها
\pend    
\endnumbering
\end{spacing}
\end{Arabic}
\end{RTL}
\end{Rightside}

\begin{Leftside} 
\begin{german}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\noindent
Wir preisen dich, Gott, für Gnadengaben, deren Lobpreis von ihrem\footnoteA{D.h. der Gnadengaben} Anwachsen kündet, und wir bitten um Segen für deinen Propheten Muḥammad, der die Gemeinde auf den rechten Weg führt.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{german}
\end{Leftside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns

\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear Maieul, thank you very much for your very fast efforts and your elucidating and comprehensive answer. I have modified my file above according to your solution, it works very fine. I have just put the \textsuperscript{} around the brackets in order to elevate them as well. Your solution even allowed to add a small additional space between the body footnote mark and the preceding word. reledmac is indeed a fantastic tool.

Comment: Dear Jans, if it is ok for you 1. Please validate answer. 2. Please vote up. 3. Please correct your first question, to pastebin what was your wrong test (because here, my answer is like your question, and not one could understand where was your problem)

Comment: I am sorry, I do not have the wrong "solution" any more, then there remains only your correct solution which is anyway an answer to the problem of customising footnote marks in reledmac.

Comment: I have restore the older version, using the history change. But please validate the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have validated your very helpful answer, first I just did not understand how to validate it, I am sorry.

Comment: Not a problem. I think you should also validate https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325100/polyglossia-does-not-work-with-hyperref-if-main-language-is-rtl (and vote up to the all the answer made to you, on the left of answer/question, you have a narrow up and a narrow down, please use them. Read https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)