# hyperref struggles with mixed script url

Tags: hyperref, urls, polyglossia

I have seen questions like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325100/polyglossia-does-not-work-with-hyperref-if-main-language-is-rtl) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6906/hyperref-scandinavian-characters-%C3%A6%C3%B8-dont-work-in-url-hyperlink-is-wrong?rq=1) but I think my question is different because it is in an RTL environment and uses non-Roman script.

I have a url that appears mixed-script in the address bar of my Chrome browser.  When I copy/paste the URL from the address bar of my browser it converts the non-ascii characters.  And hyperref is happy.

`https://ar.wikisource.org/wiki/%D8%A5%D9%86%D9%88%D9%85%D8%A7_%D8%A5%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%B4`

But in my pdf I want to give the label of the URL the appearance of a mixed-script URL, just as it appears in the browser. So the label of the URL in hyperreff needs to contain both Roman and Arabic characters.  I don't know how to get this to work. The commented-out lines in the script below tell roughly what I want, but when they are included it produces errors, understandably.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}
\let\arabicfonttt\ttfamily

\begin{document}
\href{https://ar.wikisource.org/wiki/%D8%A5%D9%86%D9%88%D9%85%D8%A7_%D8%A5%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%B4}{test}

% attempt 1
% \href{https://ar.wikisource.org/wiki/%D8%A5%D9%86%D9%88%D9%85%D8%A7_%D8%A5%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%B4}{إنوما_إليش}

% attempt 2
% \href{https://ar.wikisource.org/wiki/%D8%A5%D9%86%D9%88%D9%85%D8%A7_%D8%A5%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%B4}{\textarabic{إنوما_إليش}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an underscore (_) in your hyperlink name, which is generating the error. You probably missed it because your editor thinks it's part of a comment. You just need to escape it: `\_`

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}
\let\arabicfonttt\ttfamily
\begin{document}
\href{https://ar.wikisource.org/wiki/%D8%A5%D9%86%D9%88%D9%85%D8%A7_%D8%A5%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%B4}{إنوما\_إليش}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can't believe I missed that.